# SoundCloud upload using email

Tags: email, upload, soundcloud, friendfeed

Is there a way to use email (i.e., the SoundCloud user's registered email) to upload an audio file?  FriendFeed uses this method, which bypasses the need to integrate their APIs and solves the problem of queuing if the mobile device is not on the network when the upload request is made.  They use the subject line for title and the message content for description.  It makes it easy for any app that can email a sound to load into FriendFeed.

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't possible, but I'll raise it with the team as a feature request.

Comment: You could probably implement it yourself as a service by using an Email API like Context IO (http://context.io). That would be a pretty cool hack actually!

Answer (score 0):

This functionality can be achieved using ifttt.com connected to your SoundCloud account.

Add the IFTTT email channel and SoundCloud channel, then add this recipe: https://ifttt.com/recipes/230468-soundcloud-upload-via-email

Then simply send an email to trigger@recipe.ifttt.com with the track attached and it will automatically upload to SoundCloud as a public track.